# mongodb does not sort properly after projecting

Tags: mongodb

I am trying mongoDB v2.6.9. When I try to project and then sort I am getting a GUID for that field, instead of the real value.

Below is the query:

```
db.AuditLogs.aggregate( [ { $project: { "UserName": 1 } }, { $sort: { "UserName": 1 } } ] )
```

I get output:

```
{
    "_id" : "562ad0b83811e52f6cae384c",
    "UserName" : "63889fd9-cc1f-41d9-bf86-0eb2c3ab5be9 e6535140-d11b-4266-b7ba-971b89fa2ad1"
}
```

UserName should have string data example: "first last"

Comment: Do these GUIDs appear somewhere in your documents?

Comment: provide your AuditLogs schema

Comment: no, and it looks like 2 GUID's there?

Comment: below is a sample doc:
"_id": "562ad0b83811e52f6cae304b"
"UserName" : "Ben Rich",
"UserIdentifier" : "BenRich@test.com",
"PortalUserType" : 3,
"AgencyIdentifier" : "test",
"CustomerIdentifier" : "a99804a6-a7ae-4ac5-93d0-358d1310b71",
"AuditLogEventType" : 11,
"AuditLogEventAction" : 23,
"SessionId" : null,
"IPAddress" : "111.111.111.111",
"MetaData" : "[[\"test.png\"]]",
"Source" : "test",
"ManagementSystemType" : 1,
"CreatedDate" : ISODate("2015-09-24T15:58:54.477Z"),
"Description" : [ { "Language" : "english", "Content" : "test", "ShortContent" : "test" } ],
"SqlId" : 474665

Comment: this query:
db.AuditLogs.aggregate([ { "$project": { "UserName": 1, "insensitive": { $toLower: "$UserName" } } } ]) - WORKS



db.AuditLogs.aggregate([ { "$project": { "UserName": 1, "insensitive": { $toLower: "$UserName" } } }, { "$sort": { "insensitive": 1 } } ]) - DOES NOT WORK, I get 2 GUIDS for UserName and insensitive fields.

Comment: can I not sort after projection?

Comment: Please show the record with _id: "562ad0b83811e52f6cae384c"

Comment: @KiranD please don't post your document in the comment. Use the [edit link](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/33354577/edit) to your question to add the document  with the expected result.

Comment: I found the issue, the username did have those GUID to begin with, mwarren led me to find the issue. Thank you.